# using npm module without webpack but with inline script vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am not using webpack, I include vue as external script 
Something like this:

```
<script src ="unpckg.com/vue.js-latest"></script>
```

And I want to use npm module

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-context-menu

So I include it like this:

```
<script src= "https://unpkg.com/vue-context-menu@2.0.6/vue-context-menu.js"></script>
```

So how do I use it?
Normally I would right:

```
import contextMenu from 'vue-context-menu'
```

But it gives me an error now.

Answer (score 1):

It should be simple:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src= "https://unpkg.com/vue-context-menu@2.0.6/vue-context-menu.js"></script>

 <script>
      // This is important
      Vue.component('own-context-menu', window.VueContextMenu);
 </script>
```

[vue-context-menu](https://github.com/vmaimone/vue-context-menu/blob/master/src/index.js) registers the component on window object as:

```
window.VueContextMenu = VueContextMenu
```

Please let me know if it does not help.

Comment: yeah it works, but I wanted actually to have more general solution, imagine that I will want to use anothere module - should I look again at the code of it and try to understand what it does? Sometimes it can be not so clear)

Comment: Ohh. I understand your concern. Unfortunately, there is no way if the author has not documented it. You have to dig into the source code. Sometimes the author may not care to expose the component for script-based usage as front-end is gearing towards module-based approach and I agree that may be a bad thing. The author may also expose it via some function call for global usage. I knew about your issue because I had used this library some time back.